# Evaluate string containing html and razor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

So basically I have a html code which can also contain some razor code for instance `@Url.Action("Index", "Home")` and of course I don't want to render the '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")' to the user, I want it to get evaluated before rendering. Can that be done somehow ?

```
@Html.Raw(htmlValue) and htmlValue is razor html string
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't evaluate this code in the view if that's what you are after. Problem being, at that point you are no longer in the context of the server (which is where this code needs to be executed).

You would need to evaluate this code at the server first and then pass it down into the view (which kinda defeats the purpose of MVC), at that point you could then use [@Html.Raw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg568896%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) to output the pre-rendered content.

Answer (score 0):

`Url.Action("Index", "Home")` is a server side function that returns a string(url).

You have a cshtml file which returns html at the end of the 'razor rendering process'.
All the "server" contents are rendered using the razor engine before the page turns into html.

That means that this line: `Url.Action("Index", "Home")`

is actually going to look something like this when it gets to your client as pure html:

```
<yourserver>/Index/Home
```

You can't insert javascript properties into the Url.Action function, since this function is evaluated on the server side before the page turns into html.
What you can do, is perform an ajax call to the server with the javascript variable and it could return you a url using Url.Action.

Answer (score 0):

It was intrigued by your question and went looking for a solution.

I found [RazorGenerator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/) which seems to be possible to do some of the work by going through the cshtml file of non-ASP.NET projects.

Well, this isn't that interesting, but when you combine this with the custom generation / compilation of an assembly on runtime, you could get somewhere.

I think this is only feasible when the view doesn't change on a per request basis, that would mean you keep generating assemblies. Or you have to come up with something smart for that.